# Error specifying path for the xsd document. [using dbms_xmlschema]

Tags: sql, xml, xsd, oracle10g

My environment:

Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Product 
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.1.0  Production
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production

I need to register a "xsd" document, so that i am later able to upload corresponding XML documents into the database.

But when i run the below code i get

```
    begin
    dbms_xmlschema.registerSchema(  'http://localhost:8080/db_objects.xsd',
    xdbURIType('\public\xml\db_objects.xsd').getClob(),
    TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE
    );
    end;
```

but it throws an error:

```
    "ORA-31001: Invalid resource handle or path name "\public\xml\db_objects.xsd"
```

i felt that there is a problem with specifying the path so i tried various options like this:

but i again get the same error
       xdbURIType(C:\Users\praagarwal\public\xml\db_objects.xsd').getClob(),

Answer (score 0):

Probably should be forward slashes ..

```
xdbURIType('/public/xml/db_objects.xsd')
```

not

```
xdbURIType('\public\xml\db_objects.xsd')
```